# why my redirect code is not working but my alert is working ? please correct my code and check

Tags: javascript, redirect

Here is my code, this line `window.location = "https://www.google.com";` is not working but the `alert` is fully working. Please help me. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="pswd">Enter your password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="myInput" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Submit" onclick="checkPswd();">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
      var confirmPassword = "admin";
      var password = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      if (password == confirmPassword) {
        window.location = "https://www.google.com";
        // alert("correct");
      }
      else {
        alert("Password");
      }
    }       
  </script>
</body>        
</html>
```

Comment: Use window.location.href

Comment: I know you probably know this, but there is absolutely zero security here. Your password is readable by anyone with a browser and about a day of internet experience

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to `window.location` triggers navigation but then the JS commpletes and the normal form submission continues which triggers navigation to the form's `action` (cancelling the previous navigation instruction).

You need to cancel the default behaviour.

Typically the approach to do that would be to bind an event listener to the submit event of the form (and **not** the click event of the button).

e.g.

```
function checkPswd(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // etc...
}

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'), () => {
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', checkPswd);
});
```

---

Note, however, that any password system that involves asking the user's browser to authorise itself is pointless.